# Changing from View First to ViewModel First - How do I handle Constructor Dependency Injection

Tags: c#, ninject, mvvm-light

Our new project started out with View first pattern using  ViewModelLocator to marry the view with the viewmodel.

I'd like to change to a ViewModel first pattern.

Here is my view model constructor:

```
public DeviceSelectionViewModel(IDataModel dataModel, IMessenger messenger)
{
    if (dataModel == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("dataModel");
    if (messenger == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("messenger");

    Selector = new PlantDataTemplateSelector();
    PlantSelector = new PlantNodesSelector();
    Plants = new List<Plant>(0);

    messenger = messenger;
    messenger.Register<PlantDataLoadedMessage>(this, m => DispatcherHelper.CheckBeginInvokeOnUI(() => OnPlantDataLoaded(m.Plants)));

    RefreshData(_dataModel);
}
```

Here is how I'm now selecting the appropriate ViewModel using ViewModel first.

```
public class MainViewModel : Module
{

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        SelectedView = new DeviceSelectionViewModel();
    }

    public ViewModelBase SelectedView { get; set; }

}
```

With View first, I never directly called the ViewModel via code so the Constructor Dependency Injection worked fine.

Now that I'm calling the ViewModel via a controller ViewModel, it wants the 2 parameters for the ViewModel Constructor.

Is the proper play here to hold the references in the controller view model and pass them into the constructor? I'm missing something here with how DI works in this scenario?

I'm still putting the pieces together with DI(Ninject) and MVVM, so be kind :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We had the same issue.

You have the following choices:

- `MainViewModel` creates `DeviceViewModel` providing the values for required parameters
- `MainViewModel` gets already resolved `DeviceViewModel`

The first variant increases coupling in case when `DeviceViewModel` is exposed only for View bindings. If `MainViewModel` communicates with `DeviceViewModel` then coupling is already implied unless `MainViewModel` sees `DeviceViewModel` through some interface what inevitably requires the second option.

Another problem of the 1st approach is that in some cases nested VM can require more values for its creation as parent VM needed.
This can be solved by extending parent VM constructor to contain these additional parameters. But when (though never in practice) building complex VM graphs root VM's constructor can become bloated.

We now have a mix of both options.

All our ViewModels inherit from `ViewModelBase` abstract class. It has several overloaded constructors and most of them get `IViewModelFactory` as an input. So we can ask the factory to create `ViewModel` wee need. Wee decided not to worry about the returned type and just return the type of created ViewModel incapsulating only its creation. So it is not true DI.

We also use Messanger but our ViewModels cannot send messages explicitly and can only subscribe to the messages. We did so intentionally as a way to restrict a set of messages particular VM can send (and even subscribe to).

Comment: I get the first choice, but I can't wrap my head around the 2nd choice. Could you be so kind as to expound just a little bit on that one?

Comment: This information is very helpful. I'm looking to follow best practices whenever possible. I'm looking for a solid way to navigate via the MainViewModel. I'm sure I'll get into the deep stuff like you did. I wish I could find an open source project that had these practices in place.

Comment: I wouldn't treat my answer as best practises. We make mistakes from time to time =)